# Recursive CTE to climb a hierarchy

Tags: sql, recursive-query

I have a table called `connections` that shows mirrored user connections.

For example:

- Users 1 and 2 are connected
- Users 2 and 3 are connected
- Users 4 and 6 are connected
- Users 5 and 6 are connected

The resulting table looks like this:

| user_id | connected_to |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 5 |

I want to form sub-networks by joining all users that have other users in common and assign each of them the smallest `user_id`.

The result I'm looking for is:

| user_id | subnetwork_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 |

The logic is as follows:

1. Users 1, 2 and 3 are all connected through 2. `user_id` 1 is the smallest of all three, so `subnetwork_id` should equal 1.
2. Users 4, 5 and 6 are all connected through 6. `user_id` 4 is the smallest of all three, so `subnetwork_id` should be 4.

---

I wrote a recursive query (**will post in future edit**) that self-joins the `connections` table with itself on `user_id` and `connected_to`.

My query does not work with the second example (sub-network 4, 5 and 6) because the greatest `user_id` is the one that connects them all together.

How can I go from table `connections` to the desired result?

Comment: Why your data does not contain rows with `user_id` = 3 and `user_id` = 6? Should they have `NULL` in respective `connected_to` column?

Comment: I thought the problem would be easier to understand without mirrored connections (i.e. 1->2, 2->1). I understand why that may be relevant though, so I updated the question to reflect this change.

Comment: Does the real table include mirrored connections? Yes it would be a bit easier if the table  includes only the "lesser id connects to greater id" pattern (or  reverse only).

Comment: It does have mirrored connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using a recursive CTE.

The idea is to build a network for each node in a subquery while aggregating the `user_id` values of connected nodes in an array (`network`), which is used to stop recursion since the original connections are mirrored. Then the minimum `user_id` value from all interconnected nodes is used as a network id.

```
WITH users AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM connections
)
SELECT 
    u.user_id,
    (
        WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
            SELECT 
                c.user_id,
                ARRAY[c.user_id] AS network
            FROM connections c
            WHERE c.user_id = u.user_id
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                c.user_id, 
                ARRAY[c.user_id] || cte.network AS network
            FROM connections c                
            JOIN cte ON c.connected_to = cte.user_id 
                        AND NOT (ARRAY[c.user_id] && cte.network)
        )
        SELECT MIN(user_id) FROM cte
    ) AS subnetwork_id
FROM users u
ORDER BY user_id, subnetwork_id
```

Query output

| user_id | subnetwork_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 |

You can check a working demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=52a3553bdeffef4e807923ea10faddfe)

Answer (score 1):

I was using your first version (without mirroring), and assuming the following query should return all the connections in a single tree (assuming no loops):

```
SELECT LEAST(min(user_id), min(connected_to)) FROM (WITH RECURSIVE connect_rec AS (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        connected_to
    FROM
        connections
    WHERE
        connected_to = 1 OR user_id = 1
    UNION
        SELECT
            cc.user_id,
            cc.connected_to
        FROM
            connections cc
        INNER JOIN connect_rec rec ON (cc.connected_to = rec.user_id or cc.user_id = rec.connected_to or cc.user_id = rec.user_id or cc.connected_to = rec.connected_to)
) SELECT
    *
FROM
    connect_rec) full_connections
```

you can do a for loop for any given range (i'm just using 1..10 here, you can select until max of all values):

```
do $$
declare f record;
begin
   for counter in 1..10 loop
            for f in (SELECT LEAST(min(user_id), min(connected_to)) as min_tree FROM (WITH RECURSIVE connect_rec AS (
                SELECT user_id, connected_to
                FROM connections
                WHERE connected_to = counter OR user_id = counter
                UNION
                    SELECT cc.user_id, cc.connected_to
                    FROM connections cc
                    INNER JOIN connect_rec rec ON (cc.connected_to = rec.user_id or cc.user_id = rec.connected_to or cc.user_id = rec.user_id or cc.connected_to = rec.connected_to)) 
                    SELECT * FROM connect_rec) full_connections)
            loop 
                raise notice '% - min %', counter, f.min_tree;
            end loop;   
   end loop;
end; $$
```

the result is:

```
> notice:  1 - min 1
> notice:  2 - min 1
> notice:  3 - min 1
> notice:  4 - min 4
> notice:  5 - min 4
> notice:  6 - min 4
> notice:  7 - min <NULL>
> notice:  8 - min <NULL>
> notice:  9 - min <NULL>
> notice:  10 - min <NULL>
> OK
> Time: 0,004s
```